# deleting named ranges in VSTO

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO spreadsheet, and have re-jigged the front end. I need to change some named ranges to reflect this.

Couldn't see a good way of doing this, so I created other named ranges and pointed the code to refer to those instead.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how being a VSTO spreadsheet would make any difference to how to update a named range. Assuming you want to extend the range of cells in a named range (and assuming Excel 2007) then go to Formulas tab and click "Name Manager" and select the name you want to update. At the bottom of the form click the "Refers to" button (the one with a red arrow pointing to the top left of a range). The form will collapse to just the Refers to box and you'll be able to re-select the range. Click the 
"Refers to" button again (now with a downward pointing arrow) to return to the full "Name Manager" form. Close the "Name Manager" and OK the prompt to save changes to the range.

Your range will now refer to the new selection. Hope that is what you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

```
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(1).Delete();
```

Note: the brackets are not square, even though this is c#.